# Is there a way to convert an image into a multidimensional array of 0's and 1's

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

I want to convert an image into a multidimensional array with 0's and 1's. 
The image would be:

[image]

I wan't to store this image into an array with 'black' being stored as 1 and 'white' being stored as 0 in the array. The array would be of 8 rows and 6 columns:

```
int[,] imgArray = new int[8,6];
```

Is there a way to achieve this in C#?

Comment: What format is the image in? (bitmap?)

Comment: The image is in 'png' format. Not bitmap, however, I can use Bitmap format. I just tested code below by @Lukazoid by creating a 6*8 bitmap myself in photoshop but it didn't seem to get black as 1 as everything in the imgArray was inserted as 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e7y164x.aspx), you can populate the array like this:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\MyImage.png");
var imgArray = new int[bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height];
var blackArgb = Color.Black.ToArgb();
var whiteArgb = Color.White.ToArgb();
for (var i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; ++i)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; ++j)
    {
        var pixelCol = bitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
        if (pixelCol.ToArgb() == blackArgb)
        {
            imgArray[i, j] = 1;
        }
        else if (pixelCol.ToArgb() == whiteArgb)
        {
            imgArray[i, j] = 0;
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Pixel color must be black or white");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested the code and display tried to display the imgArray in output with: 
 
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Element({0},{1})={2}", i, j, imgArray[i, j]);

The output displays a  'System.InvalidOperationException' and the content of array is displayed 0's 
Element(0,0)=0
Element(0,1)=0
Element(0,2)=0
Element(0,3)=0
Element(0,4)=0
....

Comment: Does the invalid operation exception message match the one in my code? I've also fixed up a few coding errors which I had.

Comment: @Sujal Try my new updated answer. You have to compare the ARGB values instead of the Color instances. Tried and tested with a PNG image from MSPaint.